# Airflow Webpage to lauch

Tags: python, ubuntu, airflow

when trying to run the command: airflow webserver - i get the below error message
i am having issues getting the application to launch.
python 3.8.0
postgress latest version
Airflow Latest Version

we are having troubles finding an answer to this in the forums / through basic google searching, thank you in advance!

```
~$ airflow webserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
    from airflow.__main__ import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from airflow import settings
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 35, in <module>
    from airflow.configuration import AIRFLOW_HOME, WEBSERVER_CONFIG, conf  # NOQA F401
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 1115, in <module>
    conf = initialize_config()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 829, in initialize_config
    from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 17, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, padding
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/padding.py", line 13, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding import lib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend'
```

Comment: Any errors thrown when you installed airflow? It sounds like the cffi module is missing on the system:  You could try installing manually with `pip install cffi` but I'm wondering if you will just hit another wall after that one is cleared.

Comment: ha! exactly right my guy. installed cffi - uninstalled numpy, reinstalled pip setuptools - reinstalled numpy - and i am now able to access airflow! thank you so much!